# C# Do really need external ip for max mind services

Tags: c#, geolocation, maxmind

We are using maxmind geo ip location service in our web application. Utilizing this maxmind we need ipaddress to give as input.

We are following below snippet to get Ip address.

```
var ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
if (Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"] != null)
{
    ip = Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
    Console.WriteLine(ip + "|X-Forwarded-For");
}
else if (Request.Headers["REMOTE_ADDR"] != null)
{
    ip = Request.Headers["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    Console.WriteLine(ip + "|REMOTE_ADDR");
}
```

We are under corprate network, So in local environment as well as development environment we are used to get private ip address like this 10.X.X.X.

Using this address we always fails to locate the client location.

So real problem is when you passing external/public ip(190.X.X.X) to maxmind then only its working.

Do we really need to  get external/public ips to give input to maxmind services.

Comment: Maxmind is like datastore which has data about which IP belongs to which location. And that does not have local IPs such as starting with 10.0. Or 192.168 or 127.0.. So yes Maxmind needs external IPs only so that you can get the location of the IP. It works well when you have public facing website deployed on production.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Maxmind for IP services that has everything to do with your **clients'** IP, not yours.

- who are you trying to Geolocate?
- For fraud services, who are you trying to evaluate?

[Private IPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) are used extensively by internal networks (home and corporations/enterprises..like yours), so they are **not** unique (aside from being non-routable on the public internet, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

All geolocation providers work only on the public IP addresses. Private IP addresses are being used in LAN and can be re-issued again as long as it is not within the same LAN. There is no uniqueness to determine the geolocation information.

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly using 10.xx.xx.xx range which is is reserved for private (internal) use.

All you need do is alter your code so that prior to your Maxmind look-up you replace the "10" IP to be looked-up with a "public" one for the same locale. If your company has multiple locations then you can create an array/table of internal IPs to public "locale identifying" IPs.

e.g. if the department in LA, USA uses 10.222.xx.xx; and NY,USA uses 10.123.xx.xx addresses then for these IPs simply Maxmind Lookup with an "equivalent" public IP. so for 10.123.xx.xx (NY, USA) look up  154.16.85.37 instead.

You may not even need to use Maxmind at all for your "10 IPs". E.g. if you simply need country code; then include it in your own "IP 10" look-up table/array and for IPs prefixed 10 instead of Maxmind look-up look-up from your own table.